# Coral edge TPU Classification coordinates

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-coral

I am running my object classification using Raspberry pi 4, model B, coral edge TPU. I am using this command to classify the image.

```
‘model.classify_with_image(frame, threshold=args[“confidence”])’
```

It works perfectly but It does not give me coordinates like

```
‘model.detect_with_image()’
```

Is there any way I can get the coordinates?

From the official documentation:

```
detection:
detect_with_image(img, threshold=0.1, top_k=3, keep_aspect_ratio=False, 
relative_coord=True, resample=0)
classification:
classify_with_image(img, threshold=0.1, top_k=3, resample=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classification models shouldn't outputs any coordinates, they only output an array of probabilities between 0 and 1 associated with the labels. Objects detection models are what you would need if you want your outputs to contains object coordinates and more.
Here are some docs I suggest that you can review:
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/image_classification/overview
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview